# Move around parts of string

Tags: javascript, string, match

Say I have a string:

```
var mystring = "01/27/2016";
```

I want then to check if that string contains `/`:

```
if(mystring.match("/")){
//Then transform "01/27/2016" to "2016-01-27"
}
```

How could I achieve it?
Best Regards

Comment: Split the string ([`.split("/")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and check the length of the array. If there is only one element in the array then there is no `/` in the string. Otherwise you have the individual date parts to create a string in the required format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example:_Switching_words_in_a_string):

> `/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/gi`
>
> - 1st Capturing group `(\d+)`
>
>   `\d+` match a digit `[0-9]`
>
>   Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
> - `\/` matches the character `/` literally
> - 2nd Capturing group `(\d+)`
>
>   `\d+` match a digit `[0-9]`
>
>   Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
> - `\/` matches the character `/` literally
> - 3rd Capturing group `(\d+)`
>
>   `\d+` match a digit `[0-9]`
>
>   Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

```js
// is replacing
document.write('01/27/2016'.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/gi, '$3-$1-$2') + '<br>');

// is not replacing
document.write('01.27.2016'.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/gi, '$3-$1-$2') + '<br>');
```

Comment: But edit to also check if string contains "/". because some strings does not:)

Comment: @user1665355, it checks.

Comment: the question is to check if there is a slash in it **and** then rebuild the string with dashes. if no slasches, then nothing should happen (so my interpretation of the question).

Answer (score 1):

Solution without regex and with `split` method

```js
var mystring = "01/27/2016";
var t = mystring.split('/')
var res = t[2] + '-' + t[0] + '-' + t[1];
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res,0,2) + '</pre>');
```

---

Another solution using `Array#join` function

```js
var mystring = "01/27/2016";
var t = mystring.split('/')
var res = [t[2], t[0], t[1]].join('-');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res,0,2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
var myString = "01/27/2016";

if(myString.match("/")) {
  var array = myString.split("/");
  myString = array[2] + "-" + array[0] + "-" + array[1];
}

document.write(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you want to check if your string contains some char or another string use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

in your example

```
 if(mystring.indexOf('/') > -1){
   //Then transform "01/27/2016" to "2016-01-27"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use the library [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/guides/)

If you want change date formats MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD

```
var mystring = "01/27/2016",
    dateformatted = moment(mystring,'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```